# how to save results in text file or excel without square brackets?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am working on webscraping,I am taking names from text file by line by line and searching it on google and scraping address from that results. I want to add that result infront of respective names. this is my text file a.txt:

```
0.5BN FINHEALTH PRIVATE LIMITED
01 SYNERGY CO.
1 BY 0 SOLUTIONS
```

and this is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"

out_fl = open('a.txt','r')
for line in out_fl:
    query = line
    query = query.replace(' ', '+')
    print(line)
    URL = f"https://google.com/search?q={query}"
    print(URL)
    headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
    resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
        results = []
        newline = '\n'
        for g in soup.find_all('span', class_="i4J0ge"):
            x = f'{line}:{g.text}{newline}'
            results.append(x)
        print(results)

        with open("results.txt","a") as result:
            result.write(str(results))
```

I am getting result like this but its not formatted properly please help me out.
my expected result is like:

```
  0.5BN FINHEALTH PRIVATE LIMITED : Address: 2nd Floor, BHIVE Forum, GNS Towers #18, Dairy 
  Circle Road, Adugodi, Koramangala, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560029Hours: Closed ⋅ Opens 9:30AM 
  MonSaturdayClosedSundayClosedMonday9:30am–7:30pmTuesday9:30am–7:30pmWednesday9:30am– 
  7:30pmThursday9:30am–7:30pmFriday9:30am–7:30pmSuggest an editUnable to add this file. 
  Please check that it is a valid photo

  01 SYNERGY CO. : 01 SYNERGY CO.\n:Located in: Punjab Agricultural UniversityAddress: 3rd 
  Floor Kartar Bhawan, Ferozpur Rd, Ludhiana, Punjab 141001Hours: Closes soon ⋅ 5PM ⋅ Opens 
  9:30AM MonSaturday10am–5pmSundayClosedMonday9:30am–7:30pmTuesday9:30am– 
  7:30pmWednesday9:30am–7:30pmThursday9:30am–7:30pmFriday9:30am–7:30pmSuggest an editUnable 
  to add this file. Please check that it is a valid photo.Phone: 098159 18807
```

Or into excel. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your results to pandas data frame and than you can write it into excel or csv

```
Import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["",""].  # Assign column name as required

df = [results]

df.to_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet name', index = False)
```

Comment: can you send me what is in your query to replicate it?

Comment: everything is here only. I have "a.txt" which contains that 3 names and code is as it is.

Comment: Hope this will help
```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Company","address"])
.
.
.
df.loc[query]=[query,results]
        print(df)
        
    df.to_excel("results.xlsx",sheet_name="result", index=False)
```

Comment: I did as u said, I am getting results but now i can write only last result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870492/pandas-is-not-writing-all-the-results-it-overwrites-and-gives-only-last-result

Comment: @anshsagat check indentation thats the only issue face in such problems.

Comment: please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870492/pandas-is-not-writing-all-the-results-it-overwrites-and-gives-only-last-result